# Default "Accept" header value for Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-accept-header

If one omits the `Accept` header in a request to an Asp.Net web API the server will return `(415) Unsupported Media Type`

I am looking for a way to force the API to assume a default return type (in my case, `application/json`) when the request does not contain an `Accept` value in its headers.

After a substantial amount of reading and searching, I'm not sure this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can force the framework to use XML formatter when HTTP Accept header is missing, by doing the following trick:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
```

This way the JSON formatter will be the second registered formatter in the list, and the XML will be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This is content negotiator resposibility to choose the right formatter to serialize the response object. But by default WebApi framework gets `JsonFormatter` if could not find appropriate formatter.

> [If there are still no matches, the content negotiator simply picks the first formatter that can serialize the type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

So it is strange behavior. Anyway you could set up custom content negotiator to choose explicit `JsonFormatter` if request does not have `Accept` header.

```
public class JsonContentNegotiator : DefaultContentNegotiator
{
    protected override MediaTypeFormatterMatch MatchAcceptHeader(IEnumerable<MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue> sortedAcceptValues, MediaTypeFormatter formatter)
    {
        var defaultMatch = base.MatchAcceptHeader(sortedAcceptValues, formatter);

        if (defaultMatch == null)
        {
            //Check to find json formatter
            var jsonMediaType = formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(h => h.MediaType == "application/json");
            if (jsonMediaType != null)
            {
                return new MediaTypeFormatterMatch(formatter, jsonMediaType, 1.0, MediaTypeFormatterMatchRanking.MatchOnRequestAcceptHeaderLiteral);
            }
        }

        return defaultMatch;
    }
}
```

And replace in `HttpConfiguration` object

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator());
```